# Importing a Django model into a python cli script

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am just getting this django app (also an inexperienced python user) running and wanted to be able to access the models.

I have the following:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append('/Users/jx/dev/arc/django/second/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
from django.db import models
from testproject.models import Location
loc=Location.objects.get(name='Joes')

print loc.name
```

but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zz.py", line 6, in <module>
    from testproject.models import Location
ImportError: No module named testproject.models
```

Is there a way I can determine whether it is loading the settings.py correctly? Or is there an obvious syntax issue? Should the PYTHONPATH reflect the locations for the models (it currently doesn't if print os.environ)?

thx

Comment: i'm a dope - i didn't have the script in the django project directory. I guess this is mandatory for path info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you have added the folder containing `testproject` folder to `sys.path`. 
   For example if you have the following structure `/foo/bar/testproject/models.py` then you should add `/foo/bar` to `sys.path`
2. Make sure the `testproject` folder has a `__init__.py` file in it (which can be empty).

Answer (score 6):

Django has support for creating custom django-admin commands ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-management-commands/)).

Very useful for creating command line scripts that access the model.

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't loading your settings correctly then `from django.db import models` would have failed. As it is, your `testproject` package isn't found; add the directory containing `testproject/` to sys.path.